# Why is SQL Server Agent Job running endlessly?

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job

Currently I'm working on system that gathers data from different websites/apis and stores this data in a SQL Server database. Then reporting service generates reports based on this data.

We have a lot of jobs running in SQL Server agent (each job has some steps, each step can be of type - PowerShell script or SQL...).

Version of SQL Server is 2017.

[image]

[image]

We have a problem that almost every day there are jobs that starts but never ends (status is "Executing"). This job can not run that long.

Does anybody has an idea how to solve this problem? Or at least how to investigate it?

CPU usage on virtual machine is +- 20%. Memory usage - 50%. So it is not a resource problem.

Comment: Look for locks, either with `sp_who2` or by using the Activity Monitor?

Comment: Unpack the jobs, see what they actually do. A job can easily run forever if it's waiting for a user to press a button in a non-interactive session, for example. PowerShell itself tends to be clever enough not to do this (especially when passed the `-NonInteractive` option) but any child processes may not be.

Comment: or better, use [**sp_WhoIsActive**](http://whoisactive.com/) to check for blocking. That procedure is well documented and awesome.

Comment: If you can, throw in a pile of "at here in the code" steps that log to a SQL table or even just dump to a text file.  And then you can where it's actually hanging up.  The whole trick to this is finding where it's hanging, once you have that figured out you can solve the real problem.

Comment: @Richard Hansell didn't find any locks. BlockedBy column is empty in each row